# Parsing a semi colon delimited file in python to create a CSV

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary, tuples

I have a large text file in the below format, which I wish to convert into a CSV File. The column names on the CSV file should corrospond to the first part of the tuples seen below. Its safe to assume the first item in the line, which is not a tuple, will always be in the below format.

Other issues include each line may not have the same fields - some have for example, Statuses, some dont. Some have multiple instances of the same field, in which case I require the second part of the tuples to be concatenated (eg To Mr Smith; Mrs Green) but these are issues which are further away for now.

```
[' Message  1 '];['Status', 'Read'];['Message ID', '012434'];['Message Truncation', 'OK'];['Priority', 'Low'];['Sent Time', '15/12/2010 05:56:36']
[' Message  2 '];['ColumnName', 'Read'];['ColumnName2', '012434'];['Message Truncation', 'OK'];['Priority', 'Low'];['Sent Time', '15/12/2010 05:56:36']
[' Message  3 '];['To', 'Mr Smith'];['To', 'Mrs green'];['Message Truncation', 'OK'];['Priority', 'Low'];['Sent Time', '15/12/2013 05:56:36']
```

...

My plan is to iterate thru every block in the file to establish the column names, then start adding data to these column names, leaving blanks when appropriate. Im just wonderint how to go about this in a pythonic manner, as I've played around with a list of dictionaries and got stuck.

I think I need to split the line, then add each tuple to a dictionary. Any help?
Thanks!

```
for line in file:
    line_split = line.split(';')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using pure python...

```
infile = "listdata.txt"
data = open(infile, "r").readlines()

dataDict = []
columns = []

# Create a dictionary list
for line in data:
    row = line.split(";");
    rowData = {}
    for cell in row:
        cell = cell.strip()[1:-1].split(",")
        if len(cell) > 1:
            rowData[cell[0].strip().strip('"').strip("'")] = cell[1].strip().strip('"').strip("'")
    keys = rowData.keys()
    dataDict.append(rowData)
    columns = list(set(columns) | set(keys))

# Write dictionary list to file
outfile = "listdata.csv"
fp = open(outfile, "w")

for key in columns:
    fp.write(key + ", ")

fp.write("\n")

for data in dataDict:
    for key in columns:
        if key in data:
            fp.write(data[key] + ",")
        else:
            fp.write(",")
    fp.write("\n")

fp.close()
```

Input:

```
[' Message  1 '];['Status', 'Read'];['Message ID', '012434'];['Message Truncation', 'OK'];['Priority', 'Low'];['Sent Time', '15/12/2010 05:56:36']
[' Message  2 '];['ColumnName', 'Read'];['ColumnName2', '012434'];['Message Truncation', 'OK'];['Priority', 'Low'];['Sent Time', '15/12/2010 05:56:36']
[' Message  3 '];['To', 'Mr Smith'];['To', 'Mrs green'];['Message Truncation', 'OK'];['Priority', 'Low'];['Sent Time', '15/12/2013 05:56:36']
```

Output:

```
Status, Sent Time, To, ColumnName2, Message ID, Message Truncation, Priority, ColumnName, 
Read,15/12/2010 05:56:36,,,012434,OK,Low,,
,15/12/2010 05:56:36,,012434,,OK,Low,Read,
,15/12/2013 05:56:36,Mrs green,,,OK,Low,,
```

---

**Update**

This handles multiple entries with same type and join then with `":"`.

```
key = cell[0].strip().strip('"').strip("'")
value = cell[1].strip().strip('"').strip("'")
if key in rowData:
    rowData[key] = rowData[key] + ":" + value
else:
    rowData[key] = value
```

Comment: What should be the delimiter?

Comment: This is awesome, thank you!! I'd like to complicate things a little by saying that often, a line will have more than one 'To' cell. In this case, I would like the final CSV file to just take a delimited list of the To: people. (see message 3 in the example) I've been playing around and Ill have to make changes to the dataDict.append(rowData) line as Im assuming that when it seems a second 'To' entry, it overwrites the first one? Also, I've decided to hard-code the Column list, as it turns out I'm really only interested in 9 or so columns.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to turn each `['something', 'something_else']` block into a python list:

```
import ast

column_ids = set()

for line in file:
    columns = [tuple(ast.literal_eval(c)) for c in line.split(';')]
    columns[0] = ('id', columns[0][0]) # Give the first column a 'Id' key
    columns = dict(columns)  # turn the row into a dict
    column_ids.update(columns)
```

Adding a print statement and using your example input, that results in:

```
{'Status': 'Read', 'Sent Time': '15/12/2010 05:56:36', 'Message Truncation': 'OK', 'Message ID': '012434', 'Priority': 'Low', 'id': ' Message  1 '}
{'Sent Time': '15/12/2010 05:56:36', 'ColumnName2': '012434', 'Message Truncation': 'OK', 'Priority': 'Low', 'ColumnName': 'Read', 'id': ' Message  2 '}
{'Message Truncation': 'OK', 'To': 'Mrs green', 'Priority': 'Low', 'id': ' Message  3 ', 'Sent Time': '15/12/2013 05:56:36'}
```

and `column_ids` is:

```
set(['Status', 'Priority', 'ColumnName', 'Message Truncation', 'Message ID', 'To', 'Sent Time', 'ColumnName2', 'id'])
```

Comment: And them, the O.P. could create a set of all dict keys to get the column headers for the csv file - like in `columns = sorted( set(key for key in itertools.chain(*(dct.keys() for dct in messages))))`

Comment: @jsbueno: or you keep a set of column ids as you go, as in the updated example.

Answer (score 1):

Using pandas:

```
from pandas import *
import ast
from itertools import chain

df=read_csv('in.txt',sep=';',header=None).applymap(ast.literal_eval).ix[:,1:]
newdf=DataFrame(columns=set(i[0] for i in chain(*df.values)),index=df.index)

for row in df.iterrows():   
    for c in row[1].values:
        newdf[c[0]][row[0]]=c[1]      

newdf.to_csv('out.csv')
```